# how to access email from a shared outlook mailbox

Tags: powershell, outlook, shared

I need to get a the latest email from a shared outlook mailbox.

The shared inbox is  eg. "Server Backup"  and the email that i want to get is located 
inbox\backup report\
Here is some code that I can access my Inbox but can't do it for a subfolder

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$OutlookFolders = $Outlook.Session.Folders.Item(1).Folders
$OutlookInbox = $Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(6)
#read the latest email
$latestmail=$OutlookInbox.items | select -last 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is to navigate a little further down.

```
$outlook = New-Object -Com Outlook.Application
$MAPI = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

# Gets all mailboxes tied to the account
$Mailbox = $MAPI.Folders("SharedEmail@Company.com")

# Gets the Inbox folder
$Inbox = $mailbox.Folders("Inbox").Folders("backup report")

# Shows all emails from the Inbox
$contents = $Inbox.Items
$contents.Sort("ReceivedTime", $true)
$contents | select Subject, SenderName, CreationTime -First 1
```

EDIT: Since the above didn't work, try the below. It will search for the Inbox, then pipe that through to look for the Server Backup.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$OutlookFolders = $Outlook.Session.Folders.Item(1).Folders
(($OutlookFolders | Where-Object {$_.FolderPath -like "*Inbox*"}).Folders | `
    Where-Object {$_.FolderPath -like "*Server Backup*"}).Items | `
    select Subject, SenderName -Last 1
```

Comment: Problem #  
$Mailbox = $MAPI.Folders("BackupNotifications@xxx.xxx.xx.xx")         
I get this error
The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ $Mailbox = $MAPI.Folders("BackupNotifications@xxx.xxx.xx.xx")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
    That email is tied to the shared mailbox that i have access too. The Mailbox is called "XXX Backup Notifications"

Comment: Edited to include a second answer that may actually help in your situation.

Comment: Somehow the updated script does not connect to the shared mailbox. I will need to check with the exchange guys on this.

Comment: uhhh, try again. I fat fingered the copy paste from VS Code and added two lines from the previous solution.

Comment: When I run it it outputs nothing. So then I check the $outlookfolders and it is showing the main folders in my outlook not on the shared inbox of "Server Backup". Hmmm my head is hurting from this

Comment: Run `($OutlookFolders | Where-Object {$_.FolderPath -like "*Inbox*"}).Folders` and find where the `FolderPath` property has the "Server Backup". I am assuming that Server Backup is a sub folder of the Inbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194674/discussion-between-drew-and-goced).

Comment: Ok I have check with the exchange guys and there is a permission issues with that shared account stopping me from access it via powershell .  They can't give me access to it so that I can run these powershell commands as it will give me other access.  So looks like I will have to get to it via MAPI commands

Comment: I have my code working now on my own  inbox. using mapi                       Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$namespace.Folders.Item(1)
#gives all subfolders under 'my email account main Folder
$namespace.Folders.Item(1).Folders
#goto the inbox\backup eport and select the latest email and place it in variable $newreport
$newreport = $namespace.Folders.Item(1).Folders.Item('Inbox').Folders.item('backup_report').items | select -last 1

Comment: just need to work out how to connect to the shared mailbox

Comment: this script is not working for me . It works for personal mail id but not for shared mail id

Answer (score 0):

```
$outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$folder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
#goto the inbox\backup eport and select the latest email and place it in variable 
#$newreport
$newreport = $namespace.Folders.Item("Server 
Backup").Folders.Item('Inbox').Folders.item('backups').items | select -first 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
Add-Type -assembly "System.Runtime.Interopservices"

$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application; 

$namespace = application.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$i = 1
$Sender = "abc@123.com"     # email id
$Sender1 = "cde@123.com"    # email id

$myRecipient = $namespace.CreateRecipient("Email Id") # Email id of the shared mail box
$inbox = $Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder($myRecipient ,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)

# Save email contect to a file in a location 

$inbox.Items | ?{$_.SenderName -match $Sender -and $_.UnRead -eq "No" } |  sort receivedtime -desc | 
%{
     $Filepath = "C:\temp\" + "email" + $filecount +".txt" 
     echo $_.body | Out-File -FilePath $Filepath  #do stuff with body 
     $i = $i + 1
     $filecount = " (" + $i + ")"
     $_.Unread= $False #mark as read        
 }
 
# Save email attachment to  a location 

$inbox.Items | ?{$_.SenderName -match $Sender1 -and $_.UnRead -eq "No" } | sort receivedtime -desc | 
%{    
         $Filepath = "C:\Temp\"
         $_.attachments| ?{$_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filePath $_.FileName)) }
         $_.Unread= $False #mark as read        
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).